# How to count directories that starts with a specific letter?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to get a number of directories that start with a specific letter. I tried to get this done with:

```
find /home/test1 -type d | grep -m 1 a* | wc -l
```

but I'm getting `0` in the result no matter what I do.

Comment: `find` has a `-name` parameter, see `man find`

Comment: The -name is a better method. But for completeness: [1] grep patterns tend to contain chars that are special to shell -- it needs quoting. [2] The pattern needs to specify first character, and to use a grep pattern, not a shell one: `'^a'`. [3] grep is only reading one file (stdin pipe) so -m 1 will exit on the first line, so the count can only be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
LC_ALL=C find /home/test1//. -name 'a*' -type d |
  LC_ALL=C grep -c //
```

Or with GNU `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home/test1/ -name 'a*' -type d -printf . | wc -c
```

Remember file paths can contain newline characters, so counting *lines* is not an option.